# Application open automatically when any android mobile switched on?

Tags: android

I developed android application. But my intention is to open application automatically when mobile is switched on. For example, most of the antivirus application automatically start when mobile is switched on. Same thing I want with my application. mobile switched on application start and when I exit from application mobile switched off automatically.

Comment: use broadcast receiver and bootup start the activity http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/129747/how-to-launch-android-app-on-boot an do read the comments by mark murphy in the link posted

Comment: http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/05/boot-completed-regression.html. check this may be usefull

Answer (score 5):

This may help you

At first 
set the permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Next
add this intent filter in receiver

```
<receiver android:name=".BootReciever">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Now you can start your application's first activity from onReceive method of Receiver class..

```
public class BootReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Tabs.class);
    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(myIntent);
}

}
```

Try if this helps...

Comment: Android 10 (API level 29) and higher place restrictions on when apps can start activities when the app is running in the background. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a receiver which receives Intents reltated device switched on.
Can you clear your intentions of shutting down device when app is exited?Because there are various ways to exit from app like back button,home button.

Comment: For example when i click on home button mobile gets switched off. because no one can use other application. User can use my app only.

Comment: Hey I think you should consider Developing Custom-ROM Since you want user to use only your app and not any other.
Other-Wise you cannot achieve what you mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use...........following in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
</uses-permission>    

<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="BootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```